# Spark - Loading Config Data From DB

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

we have few spark applications (streaming and batch mode). we have some configuration data saved on our DB (from different tables). At the start of the application we need to load this data (typically 50-100 MB and even adding some buffer that it grows, shouldn't be more than 1 or 2 GB).
We have 2 options :

1. Use jdbc to load the data into a Map in a **Scala** object - this will ensure that we have this data easily accessible on each executor and can be accessed in **map/flatMap** functions during processing of each event/row in a dataframe.
2. Load as a Spark **dataset/dataframe** - this could complicate a little as we have to use joins to fetch the data with the main dataframe and then have this data pass to the **map/flatMap** functions.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of both these approaches.

I would prefer #1, as it could simplify the code without joins and also have the data accessible in the processing layer(map/flatMap), but would like to see if there are any severe disadvantages in this approach.

What is the recommended way?

Comment: Although 2 GB would be heavy-ish for a broadcast variable (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables), I still think its worth considering based on what you described.

Comment: consider #1 or #2?

Comment: #3 - use jdbc for driver to load the data and `broadcast` it to all executors.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your input - but just want to understand how is this approach better than others.